# CSV cleaning with Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm a bit new to regex and I can't get my code working. 
I've got a set of data stored in a csv. Some of them might be "dirty", i.e. not the format I'm expecting them to be. 
Typically, the data looks like this: 123.4 unit

So for example: it can be

- 0.4 %
- 1234.45 kcal/kg
- 23.245 UI/kg

So, it is a:

[unknown number of digits] + . + [unknown number of digits] + \s + [unit = bunch of characters from a to z with a "/" between them]

My code is the following:

```
def parse_csv(content, delimiter = ';'):  ##We use here ";" to parse CSV because of the European way of dealing with excel-csv
  csv_data = []
  for line in content.split('\n'):
    csv_data.append( [x.strip() for x in line.split( delimiter )] ) # strips spaces also
  return csv_data


Sans_ND=parse_csv(open('Sans_ND.csv','rU',encoding="ISO-8859-1").read())
 for row in Sans_ND:
    for i in range(1,len(row)): 
        if re.search(r"\d+\.\d+\s\b[a-z]+/[a-z]+\b",item):
            continue
        else:
            print("Formating Error",row[i],"in",row[0],"Col=",i)
```

Since the output is the entire array, and since not my entire array is badly formatted, I'm pretty sure my Regex translation of what I wanted was mediocre. 
Furthermore, I've tried to replace `[a-z]` with `\w` but it didn't improve the output.

How can I fix this? What didn't I understand about Regex here?

EDIT : WhatI mean by "dirty" is something looking like 0.4-32-0 % or 0,4 mg/kg for example.

EDIT: With the current code and the one suggested by @sln in the comments, I get for example:

```
 Formating Error 0.1 % en Arachidonic acid  col 25
 Formating Error 0.07 % en Arachidonic acid col 26
 Formating Error 0.07 % en Arachidonic acid  col 27
 Formating Error 0.08 % en Arachidonic acid  col 39
 Formating Error 0.08 % en Arachidonic acid  col 40
```

EDIT2 : with sin answer i get the same type of error. 
Here are some additional output :

```
Formatting error 350 mg/kg in Angelica root col 2
Formatting error 350 mg/kg in Angelica root  col 3
Formatting error 350 mg/kg en Angelica root col 4
```

EDIT3 : these are some inputs from the Sans_ND.csv for commentator that requested it (b3000)

```
Arachidonic acid;Arachidonic Acid;0.07 %;0.08 %;0.07 %;0.06 %
Arginine;;2.2%;2.2%;2.2%;2.2%;1.8%
Beta carotene,Beta-carotene;;1.5 mg/kg;1.5 mg/kg;0.4 mg/kg
Branched-chain amino acids,Branched-chain amino acids;;1.54 %;1.65 %;2%
```

For exemple.

Those inputs don't contain "dirty" such as given exemple of dirty formatting.

Comment: Are you getting false positives? Try loosening up the regex `\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*[a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]+`

Comment: I've tried your code and sadly it doesn't work either. Exactly. I'm getting false positives. I've updated some wrong output.

Comment: It would be helpful to also see some input to the resulting (wrong) output.

Comment: If you expect a `%` as well, you need to add that to the regex as well. `\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*(?:%|[a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]+)`

Comment: Still doesn't work. I don't understand why is that so. For the % i thought that the `\w` would contain it. But thanks for correction though !

Comment: try putting some data into http://www.regexr.com/ and play around with it until you get what you want. they also have a cheatsheet/reference.

Comment: Very good idea. Thank you for that. The regex was ok but my code was containing a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to sln, here is the answer :

```
for row in Sans_ND:
    for i in range(2,len(row)): 
        if re.match("\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*(?:%|[a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]+)",row[i]):

            continue
        else:
            print("Formatting error",row[i],"in",row[0],"col",i)
```